# SQL variable for Database Name

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pass a database name in as a parameter and execute some dynamic SQL.  As a test I created this:

```
declare @HRMSDatabase_1 nvarchar(50) = N'FirstDatabase',
        @Example_1 nvarchar(max) =
'select @HRMSDatabase'

execute sp_executesql @Example_1, N'@HRMSDatabase nvarchar(50)', @HRMSDatabase_1
```

which returns `FirstDatabase` as I expected.

When I try this:

```
declare @HRMSDatabase_2 nvarchar(50) = N'FirstDatabase',
        @Example_2 nvarchar(max) =
'select 
      ''Test''
from 
    @HRMSDatabase.dbo.hrpersnl hp'

execute sp_executesql @Example_2, N'@HRMSDatabase nvarchar(50)', @HRMSDatabase_2
```

I get an error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Is what I am trying to do possible?  I cannot simply use a `USE FirstDatabase` as I have a few databases I have to query in the same dynamic SQL using inner joins.

Also, I cannot use `SQLCMD` as this script gets executed from a GUI.

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: `Also, I cannot use SQLCMD as this script gets executed from a GUI.` - that doesnt explicitly stop you using SQLCMD! Its wrapped up as a callable utility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

Comment: Wouldn't  `from 
    @HRMSDatabase.dbo.hrpersnl hp'` need to be `from '+
    @HRMSDatabas+'.dbo.hrpersnl hp'` for the variable to be evaluated in the dynamic SQL?

Comment: Usually a sign of a broken data model - you have multiple structures (here, databases) that you wish to treat identically for querying. This usually indicates that they should in fact be a *single* data structure and the attributes that have become embedded in the object *names* should instead be present in the *data* where it's easily queried. (E.g. rather than `Sales2015` and `Sales2016` databases, there should be a `Sales` database and then the year (or date) information should be present in appropriate column(s) in the relevant table(s))

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers. Not in Sql server and probably not in any self-respecting rdbms.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I don't believe you can parameterize the database name in the table specifier. Instead try this,

```
DECLARE @HRMSDatabase NVARCHAR(50) = N'FirstDatabase';
DECLARE @Example3 NVARCHAR(MAX) ='SELECT 
        ''Test''
    FROM 
        ' + QUOTENAME(@HRMSDatabase) + '.[dbo].[hrpersnl] hp';

EXEC sp_executesql @Example3;
```

As you'll note, it's important that the `@HRMSDatabase` is not recieved from user input as this would be susceptible to injection attacks.

Comment: If you're going to the effort of enclosing the database name in `[]`s, you probably ought instead to be passing it through the `QUOTENAME` function.